# Adding a count column to a grouped query

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which i'd like to count a field which is not included in the query and i don't know how. the field i want to count is called "pic_id" from the table photo_comment

```
SELECT users_pics.wardrobe,
       profile.fname,
       users_pics.pic,
       users_pics.u_pic_id,
       users_pics.email,
       users_pics.make,
       users_pics.designer,
       photo_comment.comment  
FROM dbo.users_pics 
INNER JOIN profile      
ON users_pics.email = profile.email  
LEFT Join (             
      SELECT pic_id, 
             MAX(comment_id) max_comment_id
      FROM photo_comment              
      GROUP BY pic_id
) max_photo_comment 
ON users_pics.u_pic_id = max_photo_comment.pic_id         
LEFT JOIN photo_comment 
ON max_photo_comment.pic_id = photo_comment.pic_id AND max_photo_comment.max_comment_id = photo_comment.comment_id
WHERE users_pics.wardrobe = MMColParam AND users_pics.email = MMColParam2
ORDER BY u_pic_id asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to know how many comments are there for the "pic". I have added "COUNT(pic_id) count_pic_id" to the sub query in the Left join. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT users_pics.wardrobe, 
 profile.fname,
 users_pics.pic,
 users_pics.u_pic_id,
 users_pics.email,
 users_pics.make,
 users_pics.designer,
 photo_comment.comment,
 max_photo_comment.count_pic_id

FROM dbo.users_pics 
INNER JOIN profile ON users_pics.email = profile.email  
LEFT Join (SELECT pic_id, MAX(comment_id) max_comment_id, COUNT(pic_id) count_pic_id
           FROM photo_comment
           GROUP BY pic_id) max_photo_comment 
    On users_pics.u_pic_id = max_photo_comment.pic_id         
LEFT Join photo_comment On max_photo_comment.pic_id = photo_comment.pic_id 
    AND max_photo_comment.max_comment_id = photo_comment.comment_id
WHERE users_pics.wardrobe = MMColParam AND users_pics.email = MMColParam2
ORDER BY u_pic_id asc
```

Comment: please sorry for the bother there's another table which i'd like to add to the query and may i know if you could help me?

Comment: there's another table i would like to add to the count called pic_alb_love. there's a field in there called resp_email which you can join with the rest of the tables and i would like to count the column called comment_id

Comment: Little difficult to add your new table in without knowing the structure of pic_alb_love and it's relationship to user_pics. Please can you add the structure of the new table and the relationship to the question and I will add it to the answer.

Comment: this is the structure of the table pic_alb_love(comment_id,pic,love_com, wardrobe, email, com_name,resp_email, play_count, com_stat)

Answer (score 0):

You want to count a field that is not in your select list? you will need to add the column to your select list in order to count it and if you want to see the value of the count.

```
Select profile.fname,users_pics.pic,users_pics.u_pic_id,users_pics.email,
      users_pics.make,users_pics.designer,photo_comment.comment 
FROM dbo.users_pics 
     INNER JOIN profile      ON users_pics.email = profile.email  
     LEFT Join (SELECT  Count(DISTINCT  pic_id)  pic_id_cnt, pic_id, MAX(comment_id)       max_comment_id
FROM photo_comment              
GROUP BY pic_id         ) max_photo_comment On users_pics.u_pic_id = max_photo_comment.pic_id         
    LEFT Join photo_comment On  max_photo_comment.pic_id = photo_comment.pic_id AND    max_photo_comment.max_comment_id = photo_comment.comment_id
WHERE users_pics.wardrobe = MMColParam AND users_pics.email = MMColParam2
ORDER BY u_pic_id asc
```